# Удаление элемента в listview, неправильное отображения со смещением

Tags: java, android, listview

Даже не знаю как объяснить, в общем, запускаем активити с listview, начинаем добавлять элементы(все хорошо),начинаем удалять и начинается магия. 
Вот скрины так понятней будет:

Добавили 3 элемента, 2 элемент имеет отличие, и находиться на 2 позиции

[image: Добавили 3 элемента, 2 элемент имеет отличие, и находиться на 2 позиции]

Удалили второй элемент списка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим 3 элемент оставил свое имя но при этом взял подпись лимит.

Уже больше 4 часов сижу, не могу понять в чем же дело, если выйти из активити и опять зайти все хорошо, в списке будут 1 и 3 чистыми без лимитов. Проблема только отображения. Ставить вид по идее должен адаптер, но при дебаге он себя ведет адекватно.

Вот фрагмент кода адаптера, кода много, но в основном проверки:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Thread thread = tracker.getThread();
    ViewHolder holder;
    long days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    long eDays,eHours,eMins,eSecs;

    if(row == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
        holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
        holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        holder.start = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        holder.stop = (ButtonFloatSmall)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
        holder.textFinish = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtFinish);
        holder.textLimit = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLimit);
        holder.limDay = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limDay);
        holder.limHours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limHours);
        holder.limMin = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.limMin);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //изнальначальный вид
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalHolder.name.setText(tracker.getName());

    if(tracker.getElapsedTime()!=0 && tracker.getLimitTime()==0){//если прошедшее время !=0 и таймер без лимита
        days = tracker.getElapsedTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/360000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;
        if(days!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days));
        if(hours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <=9 ?0:"",hours));
        if(minutes!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(seconds!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
    }
    if(tracker.getIsFinished()){//если таск закончен, дошел до лимита
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/360000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getLimitTime()/1000)%60;
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(seconds!=60)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
        if(minutes!=60)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(hours!=24)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours));

    }
    if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0 && !tracker.getIsFinished()){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
        days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days, ":"));
        finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
        finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));

        eDays = (tracker.getElapsedTime() / 86400000);
        eHours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        eMins = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        eSecs = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;

        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(eSecs<=9?0:"",eSecs));
        if(eMins!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",eMins));
        if(eHours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours<= 9 ? 0 : "", eHours));
        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<= 9 ? 0 : "", eDays));


    }

    if(tracker.getIsStart() && !tracker.getIsFinished()) {//если был стартован
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btStart:
                    tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    tracker.setIsStart(true);
                    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(tracker.getUpdateTime()==0)
                        thread.start();
                    else
                        tracker.getThread().start();

                    break;
                case R.id.btStop:
                    tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tracker.setIsStart(false);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    finalHolder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    finalHolder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
  /*  Log.d("myTag","getViewTypeCount() = "+getCount());
   if(getCount()==0)
      return super.getViewTypeCount();
    else
      return getCount();*/
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Удаление элемента(удаляем из БД и из списка, который передается в адаптера, что бы вытягивать конкретный элемент и работать с ним в getView()):

```
 case ID_DELETE:
            Log.d("myTag", "previous delete trackerList.size() = " + trackerList.size());
            RemindMe.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(Tracker.TABLE_NAME, Tracker.COL_ID + "=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(acmi.id)});
            trackerList.remove(acmi.position);
            Log.d("myTag","after delete trackerList.size() = "+trackerList.size());
```

UPDATE: Мне кажется дело в паттерне ViewHolder, т.к. элемент я удаляю отовсюду, но объект статического класса продолжает хранить в себе значения уже удаленного.

Comment: Вы удаляете второй элемент, но view для второй позиции не удаляется (удаляется последний), а holder для второй позиции вы "переиспользуете". И не прячете textLimit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этот if()

```
if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0 && !tracker.getIsFinished()){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
        days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
        finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        finalHolder.limDay.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days, ":"));
        finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
        finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));

        eDays = (tracker.getElapsedTime() / 86400000);
        eHours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        eMins = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        eSecs = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;

        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(eSecs<=9?0:"",eSecs));
        if(eMins!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",eMins));
        if(eHours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours<= 9 ? 0 : "", eHours));
        if(eSecs!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<= 9 ? 0 : "", eDays));


    }
```

Надо добавить такой else

```
else {
    finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

почему? Да потому, что если лимит есть, то вы делаете видимыми эти поля, а если нету - не делаете невидимыми. А в ListView элементы списка используются повторно. И после удаления для элемента списка с номером 3 используется View от элемента списка с номером 2, в котором вы предварительно не спрятали лимит.

Comment: Огромнейшие вам спасибо, вы спасли мое время! К 3 часам ночи сегодня, я уже и сам понял, что дело в view, но не думал, что решение проблемы такое простое и примитивное) Как хорошо, что есть такие сайты. Огромное спасибо еще раз!!